# Running a process in background using jQuery loader in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the process that needs to wait. It is basically a snippet to check a website's status. The problem is if I put this in a php file without any loader, it will take some time to load the whole page.

So I think I need to use a loader to run this process in background.

Do you have any idea on how to put this function in a jQuery loader so that it runs in background, while the rest of the page loads?

```
<?php
function Visit($url){
       $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";$ch=curl_init();
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
       $page=curl_exec($ch);
       //echo curl_error($ch);
       $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       curl_close($ch);
       if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) return true;
       else return false;
}
$load = "http://www.somesite.com";
if (Visit($load))
       echo "Site is UP";
else
       echo "Site is DOWN";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this function in `page`

And then you need to specify what is the result `div`

Then you make the AJAX request

Let's make it in action

1 - assume the page is `myfunciton.php`  Not that you need to call the function

2 - `<div class="loaderResult">Loading...</div>`

3 - The AJAX code, I am going to use jQuery

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/"; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $.ajax({
      url: "myfunction.php?url="+url,
      type: "post",
      success: function(result){
          alert("success");
           $(".loaderResult").html(result);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("failure");
      }   
    });
});
```

You can pass the value of the URL in other ways

Note that the URL value now in `$_GET['url'];`

I hope this can help :)

Comment: Hey sorry for the VERY late reply. I've been trying to put the script into a file (`check.php`) and I put the JS script into another file (`script.js`). Now all I have to do is call it by a class name in HTML. I still couldn't understand how to work with AJAX. Can you guide me through this? Thanks anyway for the info.